# How to turn off Windows Form inheritance in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Every time I add a new form via Project > Add Windows Form the newly added form is an exact copy of the first form I added to the project, and all the controls lock.

I need a way to turn off the inheritance because I don't want the new form to look like the old form.

Or is there a way to unlock all the controls and delete them so the form is blank?

Comment: Is the class for one of your forms called `Form` (e.g. renamed Form1 to Form)? If so, you should rename it.

Comment: Web form? or Windows?

Comment: I was using Windows forms

Comment: then correct title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Is the class for one of your forms called Form (e.g. renamed Form1 to Form)? If so, you should rename it." @madreflection

Renaming the form from 'Form' to a different name worked.

Comment: You should _always_ give your classes decent names that describe their function...